# Zend Library Conflicts with My Own Library

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have my own lib at folder "classes". I am trying to use Zend library as standalone. (Integrating their classes into my app).

E.g. as below. Zend classes all put under a folder called Zend

> classes/db.class.php
>
> classes/Zend/translate.php ....

I use an autoload function to load classes previously.

```
if (!function_exists ("__autoload")){
function __autoload($class_name) 
{

    if(file_exists(ABSPATH.'/classes/'.$class_name.'.class.php')){
        require_once ABSPATH.'/classes/'.$class_name.'.class.php';
    }   

}
}
```

My function check if my app require my class, if so, i will load it from my "classes" folder if not it will load from Zend folder.

Whenever i call

```
require_once ABSPATH.'/classes/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'; 
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

It keep saying that my "own" classes are not loaded. I think this is an issue with Zend auto load, it check and find out that it need db.class.php in the zend folder.

How do i do this as i went to separate libraries between Zend and my Own.

Comment: I would like to use Zend autoload as it makes things so much easier, i do not need to worry about which class to require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic `__autoload` function does not support multiple autoloaders. If you specify your custom autoloader as shown above and then register a Zend autoloader, the previously installed autoloader will be overwritten by the Zend autoloader.

Since the Zend component uses spl_autoload_register(), you may also use this method (multiple autoloaders are supported - it basically installs a single autoloader that processes another stack of (user-defined) autoloaders).

http://php.net/manual/function.spl-autoload-register.php

```
// Example (requires PHP >= 5.3 because of the anonymous function)
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $fileName = ABSPATH .'/classes/'. $className .'.class.php';
    if (is_readable($fileName)) {
        require_once($fileName);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, so what spl_autoload_register() does is that it support multiple autoload so that zend autoloader when overwrite my previous autoloader? am i right?

Comment: Yes - you can define only one function with the special name `__autoload`, so that you're not able to define two autoloaders this way. `spl_autoload_register` pretty much keeps a list of all registered functions that should be considered autoloaders and calls them whenever an autoload is required, but with the side-effect that you cannot use `__autoload` anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and help. Appreciate it greatly.